# Proving that a lattice is Distributive given some condition

Tags: discrete-mathematics

The question is:

(i) Let $L$ be a distributive lattice and let $a,b,c\in L$. Prove that

($a\lor b$ = $c\lor b$ & $a\land b$ = $c\land b$) => $a$=$c$.    $(*)$

(ii) Find elements $a,b,c$ in $M_3$ violating $(*)$. Do the same for $N_5$.

(iii) Deduce that a lattice $L$ is distributive if and only if  $(*)$ holds $\forall$ $a,b,c\in L$.

My Attempt:

Well i managed to prove the first part just fine.

I am not sure about the second one, I was thinking of choosing $a=2$,$b=3$,$c=5$ for $M_3$.They do violate  $(*)$, but I am not sure whether this is correct or not.
If it is correct then probably the same example should work for $N_5$ as well.

Also i am stuck with the converse of the third part,i.e., if  $(*)$ is satified then show that $L$ is a distributive lattice.

I considered, $a\land (b\lor c)$ = $a\land (a\lor b)$ =$a$, how do I go further ?

Comment: I took lattice theory a long time ago. I think I remember what $M_3$ and $N_5$ are but I'm not sure. Could you please remind me?

Comment: @bof $M_3$ is the diamond lattice and $N_5$ is the pentagon lattice.

Comment: That's what I thought but I didn't know they had elements named $2$, $3$, and $5$.

Comment: So how come you're "not sure" about (ii)? In $M_3$ you take the three incomparable elements $a,b,c$; then $a\vee b=c\vee b=1$ and $a\wedge b=c\wedge b=0$ while $a\ne c$. In $N_5$ you have $0\lt a\lt c\lt1$ and $0\lt b\lt1$ and $a,c$ incomparable with $b$ and the same stuff happens. So (\*) holds in every distributive lattice but fails in $M_3$ and $N_5$. Since every non-distributive lattice contains $M_3$ or $N_5$ as a sublattice, (*) fails in every non-distributive lattice, Q.E.D.

Comment: @bof Well, I am very new at this and i could be completely wrong by giving those values to $a$,$b$ and $c$.Nothing else came to my mind when the question asked for elements in $M_3$ and $N_5$.

Comment: I didn't know $2,3,5$ were elements of $M_3$ or $N_5$. I thought they were just abstract lattices; I didn't know they had any specific elements.

Comment: So the elements of $N_5$ are $0,1,2,3,5$? How are they ordered?

Comment: @bof Well i think that it is probably incorrect to say that elements of $N_5$ are 0,1,2,3,5.I was probably wrong in the first place, i just checked right now, in general $N_5$ is given by{$0,a,b,c,1$}

Comment: And how are $a,b,c$ ordered? Is $a\lt c$ for instance?>

Comment: @bof Yes, but i am more used to using $a>c$.

Comment: By "yes" you mean "no". All right, in $N_5$ you have $0\lt c\lt a\lt1$ and $0\lt b\lt1$, while $a$ & $b$ are incomparable, as are $c$ & $b$. Right? It seems confusing that $a,b,c$ are the fixed **names** of the elements of $N_5$, and are also used as **variables** in your equation (\*). Luckily, you don't have to rename anything, they are just the $a,b,c$ you want for your counterexample: $a\vee b=c\vee b=1$, etc.

Comment: @bof Alright, got it.So I'll just use $a$,$b$,$c$ as $a$,$b$,$c$ then. Thank you.Also could you help me out with the third part as well ?!

Comment: I already did, four or five comments back. If (\*) holds for all elements in $L$, then because of (ii) it follows that $L$ can't have $M_3$ or $N_5$ as a sublattice. Therefore, $L$ is distributive. (I assume you've already had that characterization of distributive lattices.)

Comment: @bof Thanks I got it now !